# Can't display code output onto phone screen or web browser using expo (Metro bundler)

Tags: react-native, expo

The web browser says "Uncaught Error
No safe area value available. Make sure you are rendering `<SafeAreaProvider>` at the top of your app." and then on the phone (Expo Go) it says, "Welcome to Expo start by creating a file in the C: ... directory"
"Touch C: User\ ....app/index.js"
how do I fix this issue so my phone could show my layout with the word "home?"

Here is my code under the app folder> index.js file:

```
import { View, Text} from 'react-native';

const Home = () => 
 {
    return(

        <View>
            <Text>Home</Text>
        </View>

    )
}

export default Home;
```

and I have another file in app folder called _layout.js:

```
`import { Stack } from 'expo-router';

const Layout = () => 
{
    return <Stack />;
}

export default Layout;`
```

I tried importing safeview and surrounding the view with it but it didnt work.